# Why did I receive lots of warning message when running the TensorFlow example?

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter

I am following the tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started

Why did I receive lots of errors as below? Also, the final loss score is different. The documentation says:

```
{'global_step': 1000, 'loss': 1.9650059e-11}
```

while my loss is:   `{'loss': 6.3995182e-09, 'global_step': 1000}`

```
import tensorflow as tf
# NumPy is often used to load, manipulate and preprocess data.
import numpy as np

# Declare list of features. We only have one real-valued feature. There are many
# other types of columns that are more complicated and useful.
features = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("x", dimension=1)]

# An estimator is the front end to invoke training (fitting) and evaluation
# (inference). There are many predefined types like linear regression,
# logistic regression, linear classification, logistic classification, and
# many neural network classifiers and regressors. The following code
# provides an estimator that does linear regression.
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features)

# TensorFlow provides many helper methods to read and set up data sets.
# Here we use `numpy_input_fn`. We have to tell the function how many batches
# of data (num_epochs) we want and how big each batch should be.
x = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y = np.array([0., -1., -2., -3.])
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x":x}, y, batch_size=4,
                                              num_epochs=1000)

# We can invoke 1000 training steps by invoking the `fit` method and passing the
# training data set.
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)

# Here we evaluate how well our model did. In a real example, we would want
# to use a separate validation and testing data set to avoid overfitting.
print(estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn))

INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_task_type': None, '_task_id': 0, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x7f1555e351d0>, '_master': '', '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 0, '_environment': 'local', '_is_chief': True, '_evaluation_master': '', '_tf_config': gpu_options {
  per_process_gpu_memory_fraction: 1.0
}
, '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_model_dir': None}
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: /tmp/tmpol66d18y
WARNING:tensorflow:Rank of input Tensor (1) should be the same as output_rank (2) for column. Will attempt to expand dims. It is highly recommended that you resize your input, as this behavior may change.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/abigail/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/head.py:615: scalar_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that TensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, passing a tensor or list of tags to a scalar summary op is no longer supported.
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1 into /tmp/tmpol66d18y/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 2.25, step = 1
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2197.95
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0537609, step = 101 (0.047 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2106.83
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0114769, step = 201 (0.047 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2184.51
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.00149274, step = 301 (0.046 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2126.71
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.000284785, step = 401 (0.047 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2112.6
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3.2641e-05, step = 501 (0.048 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2048.21
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3.71825e-06, step = 601 (0.048 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2154.48
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.1719e-06, step = 701 (0.047 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2287.71
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.42258e-07, step = 801 (0.043 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 3059.53
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 7.27343e-08, step = 901 (0.033 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1000 into /tmp/tmpol66d18y/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 6.50745e-09.
WARNING:tensorflow:Rank of input Tensor (1) should be the same as output_rank (2) for column. Will attempt to expand dims. It is highly recommended that you resize your input, as this behavior may change.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/abigail/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/head.py:615: scalar_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that TensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, passing a tensor or list of tags to a scalar summary op is no longer supported.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2017-05-08-06:39:50
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tmp/tmpol66d18y/model.ckpt-1000
INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2017-05-08-06:39:51
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 1000: global_step = 1000, loss = 6.39952e-09
WARNING:tensorflow:Skipping summary for global_step, must be a float or np.float32.
{'loss': 6.3995182e-09, 'global_step': 1000}
```

Comment: 1. Final loss can be different because of random initialization of weights. So, no need to worry about the loss as it is decreasing with number of steps. 2. Warning might be because of TF version you are using. Can you try updating to latest TF version and run it again. (I am using TF 1.0 and getting those same warnings)

Answer (score 1):

It has been clearly mentioned that you are using a temporary folder to store your model. To fix this issue you just have to make a change in the estimator statement. Change

```
estimator=tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns = feature_columns)
```

to

```
estimator=tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns = feature_columns, model_dir="D:\test") #Or any other directory as per your wish
```

And the answer is not exact because of the training model we are preparing undergoes Runtime Errors during the process of Training.Therefore don't Worry about the difference you get from the model but rather focus on that the loss is almost zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as expected.

Because of issues like random initialization, you don't expect to get precisely the same numerical loss each time you run the program. (You can try setting the Tensorflow graph random seed to a fixed value if you want deterministic output.)

The warning and info messages are benign; I agree they are a little scary looking. The info messages you can ignore pretty much always. Just ignore the warning messages for now too; I asked the authors of the tutorial to update it so they go away.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's very annoying. You can suppress it by adding this line:

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
```